# Live Keyboard Output Change

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi (*I’m sorry for my english in advance*) I need help.

I’m kind of new in python and I’m trying something for which I can’t seem to find any help anywhere online. Long story short I’m trying to create a way to do the following:

when ever I start my script it will change my keyboard ***Live*** output **I'm not trying to print**. Let’s say I opened “Notepad” and I start typing. When typing if I press “*A*” it will type “*B*”

so for example if I type “*Apple*” it will be “*Bhhil*”(*its just an exp*).

the only way I’m getting near this result is by using the Library “*pynput*” and “*keyboard*” but the way I’m doing it is not efficient. I’ll explain the process:

if I detect lets say the letter “*A*” and in my script this letter is set to be replaced by “*B*” my script will press “*backspace*” and then type “*B*”. But using it that way I used to have a problem with the "*listener*", he used to be stuck in a loop every time I change "*A*" To "*B*" since the way to change it is by "*virtually*" pressing and releasing the keyboard it will change the "*B*" To a "*C*" etc...
I managed to come around a solution by stop the listener when sending the "*B*" command.

Now the problem I'm having is that the script is working perfectly but after I stop it using "CTRL + C" (KeyboardInterrupt)

***this is the tricky part to explain:***

It send keys to my keyboard (*probably the keys I've pressed earlier*) and I can't managed to stop it.

Sorry I don't know if I made my self clear but here is the code bellow, if you can try it and help me I would be grateful, and yes my code is a mess and yes maybe python is not the correct language to do that type of thing but I really want to achieve it using Python and yes I'm new to python so please don't be rude on me :)

```
from keyboard import press, release
from pynput.keyboard import Listener


class changeOutput:

    def __init__(self):
        self.alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
                      's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

        self.invertedAlpha = ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'u', 't', 's', 'r', 'q', 'p', 'o', 'n', 'm', 'l', 'k',
                              'j', 'i', 'h', 'g', 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']

        self.stop = True  # Stop The Listener

    def on_press(self, key):
        try:
            clearKey = str(key).replace("'", "")  # 'a' --> a

            if clearKey in self.alpha:
                self.stop = False
                press('backspace')
                press(self.invertedAlpha[self.alpha.index(clearKey)])
                self.stop = True
                self.start(stop=self.stop)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.stop = False
            self.start(stop=False)
            return False

    def on_release(self, key):
        try:
            clearKey = str(key).replace("'", "")  # 'a' --> a

            if clearKey in self.alpha:
                release(self.invertedAlpha[self.alpha.index(clearKey)])
                self.stop = True
                self.start(stop=self.stop)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.stop = False
            return False

    def start(self, stop):
        while stop is True:
            try:
                with Listener(on_press=self.on_press, on_release=self.on_release) as listener:
                    listener.join()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    changeOutput().start(stop=True)
```